# How to draw simple bar chart for the following data?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, draw, charts

I need to draw a simple bar chart for the following sample data. I checked some example but they are very difficult to understand. I used a `tikzpicture` environment.

```
 \begin{filecontents*}{data3.csv}
Test Hard      Soft 
a 25.12221  26.34338
b 23.55208  23.55208
c 17.74874  26.8047
d 18.47252  28.57218
e 21.07144  34.25253
\end{filecontents*}
```

I need to draw a graph that looks like the one below.  these one set (25.12221  26.34338) bring as Test 1, like wise

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275730/, it seems that your question is duplicate to it.

Comment: @Zarko can yo uplease help me , show how to it apply to data retive , defined .csv file .. ?

Comment: In given link is showed, how to do this. However, meanwhile you receive answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe something like this should work. Note that the more information you provide, the better and faster the help will be. If you used a `tikzpicture` post the code, it will show that you put a little effort into your question.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data3.csv}
    Test Hard      Soft 
    a 25.12221  26.34338
    b 23.55208  23.55208
    c 17.74874  26.8047
    d 18.47252  28.57218
    e 21.07144  34.25253
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[ybar,xmajorgrids=false,xtick={1,2,3,4,5},xticklabels={a,b,c,d,e},typeset ticklabels with strut]
    \addplot[draw=none,fill=orange] table[col sep=space, x expr={\coordindex+1}, y expr=\thisrow{Hard}] {data3.csv};
    \addplot[draw=none,fill=blue!75] table[col sep=space, x expr={\coordindex+1}, y expr=\thisrow{Soft}] {data3.csv};
    \legend{Hard,Soft}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]